# PowerPoint 2010 stuttering on mp4 playback

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

I have the following:

- PowerPoint 2010 32bit,
- pptx file
- Embedded mp4 file 10MB in size

Playback machine:

- Dell Latitude e6230
- i5-3320M
- 8GB RAM
- 256GB SSD
- Win7 x64
- Klite codec pack 10.15
- Intel video card drivers 15338
- Quicktime 7

Playing back video is fine via quicktime / vlc / windows media player

PowerPoint 2013 plays back fine - same machine (side by side install).

Same file on a machine with an ATI video card plays back fine as well.

Does PowerPoint 2010 with Intel drivers just not work for mp4s, do I just convert all videos to WMV to ensure they play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an a BIG problem getting MP4 Files to run in PowerPoint 2010. They would stutter and break up.

I was using YouTube Downloader (YTD) and it was giving me a file that would run from the desktop, but not in PowerPoint.  I am now using RealPlayer Cloud or Savefromnet and am inserting MP4s with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading machines to Office 2013. Loring's answer may help.